# about the waste-sorting OR with waste-sorting

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

Which sentence is correct between those two:

> The problems about the waste-sorting are ...
>
> The problems with waste-sorting are ...

Comment: Which one  do you think is correct?

Answer (score 1):

> The problems about the waste-sorting are ...
>   The problems with waste-sorting are...

Both sentences are correct.

"The problem(s) with ..." is a common noun phrase (as part of a phrase). "The problem(s) about ..." is similar noun phrase but "with" is used more often (as far as I've experienced) and can sound more natural.